# Tiles generate reflected latters and also doesn't implement the image

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I am a Beginner.

in my visual studio for express phone 2013 using c# there is in my app consider the many internal tiles. tiles showing reflected latters and also doesn't showing image.
how to navigate another page when tiles clicked. I have created tiles using the  `xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"`
my source code is

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,0,0,0"  >
    <toolkit:WrapPanel x:Name="horizontalWrapPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <toolkit:HubTile  Title="Quadratic Equation"   Source="C:\SEM'S\windows dev center\samples\HubTilesPanorama\HubTilesPanorama\Images\quadratic equ.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Background="#696969" GroupTag="StaticHubTile"/>
        <toolkit:HubTile Title="Logarithm"  Source="/HubTilesPanorama;component/Images/logaritham.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="12,0,0,0" Background="#696969" GroupTag="StaticHubTile"/>
        <toolkit:HubTile Title="Polynomials"  Source="/HubTilesPanorama;component/Images/polynomials.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="12,0,0,0" Background="#696969" GroupTag="StaticHubTile"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

how to navigate another page through click on that tiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Check if Images are Showing or not. It must Show by this Code below. Check that you are `passing right path of images` or not.

XAML:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="12,0,0,0"  >
        <toolkit:WrapPanel x:Name="horizontalWrapPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <toolkit:HubTile  Title="Quadratic Equation"   Source="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Background="#696969" GroupTag="StaticHubTile" Tap="HubTile_Tap"/>
            <toolkit:HubTile Title="Logarithm"  Source="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="12,0,0,0" Background="#696969" GroupTag="StaticHubTile" Tap="HubTile_Tap"/>
            <toolkit:HubTile Title="Polynomials"  Source="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="12,0,0,0" Background="#696969" GroupTag="StaticHubTile" Tap="HubTile_Tap"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

CS:

```
private void HubTile_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: thnxx but doesn't works same problem occurred there is designer shows image and latter are perfectly but my device and emulator doesn't show
now what to do??? can you give me your email id then i send screenshot to you. because  i haven't enough  Reputation to upload image.
  
cs is very helpful thanxx